# react native - android - Picker has underline

Tags: android, react-native, picker, native-base

Have a problem with `Picker` style - it has underline like `TextInput` on Android, but `underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'` or any other color isn't working.
[image]

I'm using `Picker` from NativeBase, and this `Picker` replaces ReactNative `Picker`. So here is my code. I've tryed wrapped `Item` with `Input`(NativeBase) or `TextInput` with `underlineColorAndroid` property, because only TextInput can have this prop, but has no luck. Changing styles of the components with bottomBorderColor doesn't give a result too. Can anyone help me please?

```
          <View>
             <Form>
               <Item inlineLabel>
                 <Label>Region</Label>

                 <Picker
                   style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', width: 200 }}
                   placeholder='...'
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="..."/> //this first Item rendered as underlined
                 </Picker>
               </Item>
           </Form>
      </View>
```

Comment: so each `Item` in `Form` has underline, and it looks like there are 1 line under `Label` and 2 lines under `Picker`

Comment: The underline is supposed to act as item divider in Picker. Why do you want to remove that underline?

Comment: @wlisrausr please look at the image above

Comment: Ooh, okay. So which border that you want to remove? Border in `Item` or `Picker`?

Comment: @wlisrausr Picker's border. Actually on iOS or Android later than 4.4.3 there are no double borders, only Form Item's bottom line

Comment: I am facing a double border. One is in above and another one is below in iOS platform

Answer (score 0):

Add `style={{borderColor:"transparent"}}` to the `<Item>` tag.

```
         <View>
             <Form>
               <Item inlineLabel style={{borderColor: "transparent"}}>
                 <Label>Region</Label>

                 <Picker
                   style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', width: 200 }}
                   placeholder='...'
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="..."/> //this first Item rendered as underlined
                 </Picker>
               </Item>
           </Form>
      </View>
```